# How can I prevent systemd from freezing my system when Flash dies?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, firefox, freeze, adobe-flash

Since a recent update, when I quit a web page containing a Flash animation in Firefox, the `plugin-container` process becomes a zombie, and then the `systemd-journald` process (also maybe something like `systemd-coredump` sometimes) eats several hundreds megabytes of memory. I don't have much RAM, so it makes my system swap, and when my system swaps it freezes.

How can I prevent that? Should I disable something related to logging or core dumps? I'm using an up-to-date Archlinux system, with Firefox 30.0, systemd 213-9 and Flash 11.2.202.378.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Disabling_application_crash_dumps_journaling), you can run this to disable crash dump journaling:

```
# ln -s /dev/null /etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf
# sysctl kernel.core_pattern=core
```